# ASP .Net After I change temp folder: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, exception, temporary-directory

I have a webapplication, which is making pdf files from a database, using Entity Framework and ITextSharp, on a free host. (somee.com) But if I make several different files, the default temp folder gets full and I get a "Theres not enough disk space" exception. So I decided to change the temp folder to my webapplication folder /App_Data/Temp.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" tempDirectory="D:\DZHosts\LocalUser\user\webapp\App_Data\Temp">
```

But after that, I can't use my application, because I get an exception:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. There is not enough space on the disk. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070070)
```

I have enough space. What should I do about it?

Comment: The exception is pretty clear. The disk is full. If the system disk (usually C:) is full, lots of things stop working.

Comment: But it is a free host, and I changed the temp folder to my own directory, which has at least 90 mb free space. If I don't change the temp folder, the application starts, but I believe users have some limit on the default temp folder, that is why I can't make multiple files. After I change the temp folder, the created folder is empty.